# How to get react app to scroll when overflow isn't detected?

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, overflow, create-react-app

I am new to web dev and have started using the create-react-app to start my own website. I'm running into an issue where the content cannot fit on the screen but I cannot seem to get my site to scroll. I've added the following code to the index.css file and the scroll shows up without a scroll bar. I think it's because the site hasn't detected overflow. However, I do not know how to fix this

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page will only scroll once the height of the html element has exceeded the window height.